# Can I disable profanities on Civilization VI?

Tags: civilization-6

According to ESRB, there are profanities in the villains dialogue boxes and I'd prefer to remove them.  If there is no filter option, but the dialogue is unimportant for the game, I would also be ok with disabling the dialogue if that is an option.  Basically, I just want a way to disable the profanities without breaking the game.  Thanks!

Comment: I opted to edit for Civ 6 since the game is newer and the title is such. OP feel free to adjust if needed and make the question for 5, the answer will change though.

Comment: sorry about that @n_plum you are correct i meant civ 6

Comment: Please provide a citation for the profanities, otherwise this is just slandering a game.

Comment: @Sjoerd Im unsure of what you mean by a citation. If you mean listing them, I'm refraining from this because I'm pretty sure that's against the stackexchange rules

Comment: You could cite the dialogue that includes profanity but blank out the profanities themselves.

Comment: @Kyralessa, Unfortunately ESRB doesn't include any of the dialogue with the profanities, they just say that it is included, and I haven't seen any of it myself.

Comment: This is one place to look; go to this link and click on the Language box: [Common Sense Media: Civ 6](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/game-reviews/sid-meiers-civilization-vi)  The profanity it cites there is mild, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't recall any profanity in the Civ VI dialogues but you have a few options to help, most of which don't involve removing the dialogue altogether unfortunately.

1. Hit the <kbd>esc</kbd> key. It will skip the audio and get you to the response options faster.
2. Install the [CQUI mod](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2115302648) - it gets the selection boxes to appear without delay.
3. Install the [NQmod](https://www.reddit.com/r/nqmod/comments/5b9n5q/new_page_for_civ_6_mods/), removes most of the unnecessary parts of the diplomacy screen.
4. Go to the settings, Graphics Options, and disable leader animations. It will help you get off the screen faster similar to using the <kbd>esc</kbd> option.